Inserting Cell Values into a String to send a command to equipment
I am trying to inset some cell values into a command to send to control a piece of equipment.
The command has to be sent to the equipment as a string with the cell values replacing the two variables below. Is there a way to insert these in the string and then send the string to the equipment?
Private Sub Move_text_Click()
Dim receive_response As String
Dim jobNumber As Integer
Dim oFfset As Double

    jobNumber = Range("G12").Value
    oFfset = Range("AH10").Value
    
    
    receive_response = MBActX1.Comm.SendAndReceive("WX,JOB=jobNumber,OnTheFlyTriggerDelay=119.5, oFfset ")
        Debug.Print receive_response

Example:
Say if the cell values are as follows jobNumber = 6 and oFfset = 2.0 the resulting string should be
receive_response = MBActX1.Comm.SendAndReceive("WX,JOB=6,OnTheFlyTriggerDelay=119.5,2.0")
The command will then be sent to the equipment in order to adjust the variables for that job.

This looks like VBA for Excel.
In VBA you can concatenate string using the "&" operator as in the following case:
Range("A10").Value = "WX,JOB=" & jobNumber & ",OnTheFlyTriggerDelay=119.5," & oFfset

I just tried it using integer and double and got the following value in the A10 cell
WX,JOB=6,OnTheFlyTriggerDelay=119.5,2.5

For more VBA syntax and tips and tricks this is my go-to:
https://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html
Hope that fixes it.
